# How to smoothen out extrusion on a curved surface

Tags: edit-mode, extrude, smooth

Say I have a curved surface with some extruded text on it:
[image]

What is the best way to remove that extrusion to best approximate the original curve? In other words, transform the above image into the underlying curve like this:
[image]

With extrusions on flat surfaces, I would usually resort to the typical S -> [dimension] -> 0 method, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I can do in situations like this. All the better if the method also works with etchings, or if there is an alternative for that case.

Comment: You can keep the top edge loop only, remove the rest, and extrude down this edge loop on Z?

Comment: .. or keep top and bottom edge-loops only. and _Bridge Edge Loops_ between them.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your first image, the writings don't share any vertex with the surface. I that's true, they should be easy to select with the "Select Linked" function (hover your mouse on the writing then press L), and therefore easy to delete.

Comment: What is the purpose of smoothing out extrusion?

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? @moonboots

Comment: Could you share a step-by-step on how to do that? @RobinBetts

Comment: @thibsert that's true, but I made this as an example just to demonstrate what I was talking about. Most of the time when I want to do this, it's with a model that is fully connected.

Comment: @vklidu there are a few different scenarios when I want to do this. For example, I downloaded a 3d model of a book that had extruded text on the side, which is curved. In that case, I wanted to keep the model of the book, but the text didn't fit my purpose.

Comment: If you don't need text topology select rectangular area of this part of mesh delete and search for **Grid Fill** operator. At letdown corner you can adjust some properties. If you want to keep text topology, but just flatten, try Sculpt brush Flatten.